# Flask WTForm Creating WTForm's SelectField Element dynamically

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a table in my database that houses some staff and each staff has an allocated **task id**. I want to dynamically create select fields according to the number of staff that has a particular task id. For example, if there are **3** staff with task id **1**, there will be three select fields (with **5** dropdown items each)
In form.py

```
 class DynamicForm(Form):
    @classmethod 
    def append_field(cls, name, field):
        setattr(cls, name, field)
        return cls
```

In routes.py -- main file

```
assigns = Project_Users.query.filter_by(project_id=id).all() 
// query the database to get all the staff under the project using the project id 
l = len(assigns) // length/ number of staff

d = DynamicForm() // from form.py
for e in range(l):         
  d.append_field(assigns[e].admin.first_name,SelectField(assigns[e].admin.first_name, validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[('0', 'No Task'),( '1','Site Acquisition'),('2','Installation'),('3','Configuration'), ('4','Commission')]))

    d.append_field('submit', SubmitField('SAVE')) // this is outside the for loop
```

In html template

```
<form action="/project/{{ project.id }}/tasks" method="POST">
                  {{ d.hidden_tag() }}
                <table class="table is-stripped" style="width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                      {% for g in d %}
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{ g.label }}</td>
                        <td>{{ g }}</td>
                      </tr>
                      {% endfor %}

                      </tbody>
                  </table>
              </form>
```

The codes above is working, but it does not change and the number of staff changes for example, project 1 has 3 staff and it rendered three selectfields but when project 2 which has 2 staff is rendered 3 staff and 3 selectfields appears

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing your form dynamically overwriting the constructor with arguments:

```
class DynamicForm(Form):
    submit = SubmitField

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        assigns = Project_Users.query.filter_by(project_id=kwargs['id']).all()
        for ass in assigns:         
            setattr(DynamicForm,
                    ass.admin.first_name,
                    SelectField(ass.admin.first_name, 
                                validators=[DataRequired()], 
                                choices=[('0', 'No Task'),
                                         ( '1','Site Acquisition'),
                                         ('2','Installation'),
                                         ('3','Configuration'),
                                         ('4','Commission')]))
        super().__init__()
```

Then you call it like

```
d = DynamicForm(id=1)
```

Technically the difference between this and your form is that you add class level attributes after you have initialised the form, and after the base `Form` has run. I.e there is a difference between:

```
DynamicForm(Form):
    def __init__(self)
        super().__init__() # calls Form.__init__()
        # extra stuff
```

and

```
DynamicForm(Form):
    def __init__(self)
        # extra stuff
        super().__init__() # calls Form.__init__() and acts on extra stuff.
```